# Why doesn't 教 end in"-う"?

Tags: verbs, godan-verbs

Wiktionary says that 教, read as きょお means "to teach". However, I have read that in dictionaries, al forms end in "-う" and not in "-お". Why is 教 different?

EDIT: Yes, it says that in English wiktionary. First, the reading they give is "kyoo". Second, they define it as "1.to teach; teachings"

Comment: I can't find a page on Wiktionary that gives きょお as a reading for 教.  I think you might be mixing a couple things up conceptually but the question is hard for me to understand the way it's written, so I'm not sure.

Comment: No, neither [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%95%99#Japanese) nor Japanese [wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%95%99#.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E8.AA.9E) does say that.

Comment: It's true that 教{きょう} doesn't end in /u/ (though it does end in う, this is just a spelling that doesn't reflect the actual pronunciation of the morpheme), and verbs do end in /u/ in the form listed in dictionaries (but not necessarily う), but that doesn't apply here because this is a bound morpheme and not a verb.  Have I correctly guessed the mistakes you're making?

Comment: The main mistake, I think, you're making is that you're looking at a kanji, not a word. Kanji are not words.

Answer (score 3):

This is a serious misunderstanding, I'm afraid. きょう is just one of the several readings ([読]{よ}み[方]{かた}) of 教. It's a so-called 'sound-reading' [音読み]{おんよみ}, which are Japanese renderings of Chinese speech. You actually misquoted this particular reading; it's きょ**う** not きょ**お**, although that would be pronounced the same way. But as far as Japanese verbs go, that's irrelevant; you have to look for the 'explanatory reading' [訓読み]{くんよみ}, which gives you a Japanese word that has (more or less) the same meaning as the original Chinese word. Wiktionary has the following to say:

#### Readings

```
Goon: きょう (kyō) < けう (keu)
Kan’on: こう (kō) < かう (kau) (non-Jōyō reading)
Kun: おしえる (教える, oshieru), おしえ (教え, oshie), おそわる (教わる, osowaru)
```

As you can see, all of the multiple kun readings do end in -u. Only these forms may be conjugated.

Answer (score 0):

All the Kun endings do end in "u". I believe it is only necessary that the Kun end in U
教 common
Kun おし.えるoshi.eru    おそ.わるoso.waru
teach;  faith;  doctrine
Radical: 攵 (rap).   Strokes: 11画.   Elements: 子⺹攵.   Pinyin: jiào / jiāo.   Hangul: 교 [gyo].   Nanori: のり / ひさ.
Jōyō Kanji 2nd Grade.   JLPT N4.
Example compounds:
キョウ 教条主義【きょうじょうしゅぎ】dogmatism
聖教【せいきょう】sacred teachings; Confucianism; Christianity
教化【きょうか】culture; education; civilization; civilisation
おしえる    教える【おしえる】to teach; to inform; to instruct
英語を教える【えいごをおしえる】to teach English
おそわる    教わる【おそわる】to be taught
▸ Codes and indices
▸ Find words containing 教 / beginning with 教 / ending with 教 / 教_ / _教

Comment: This format is pretty hard to read. Perhaps you can improve it with markup.